# CoreUi Laravel + Vue error - I cant integrate vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, core-ui

I am using CoreUI Free Bootstrap Admin Template in Laravel (6.x). Vue are integrate.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@coreui/coreui": "3.0.0-beta.3",
    "@coreui/coreui-chartjs": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "@coreui/icons": "1.0.0-beta.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "pace-progress": "1.0.2",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.4.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^6.0.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.23.6",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8"
  },
```

by default, in coreUI there are one vue component.

```
   <template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

and by default, this is app.js archive

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

then, i try to do the first component of vue in CoreUI with Laravel, like this

```
@extends('dashboard.base')

@section('content')
    <example-component></example-component>
@endsection
```

Before that, i do

```
php artisan serve
npm run watch
```

The example componen dont work.

Someone knows the error? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Js1p.jpg)

Comment: Please share error message

Comment: The error is that dont print the vue element.
i put de vue element In welcome.blade.php , and dont appear in browser

Comment: You can better use https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-vue-laravel-admin-template which is all working. Your image shows that the style hasn't loaded. The welcome.blade.php does not have vue integrated. Check route, check blade file